# Opening Multiple password protected files in excel vb using referenced cells for path but second run through code creates error

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

First part of code to Open Timesheet 02 works perfectly but on second round for Timesheet 03 the process bugs out when confirming file exists.  Both sections are identical except for cell references.

' Open Timesheet Row 02

```
Dim TimeSheet02 As Workbook

If Dir(Sheets("Command Sheet").Range("H2").Value, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "The Full path of " & Sheets("Command Sheet").Range("H2").Value & " does not exist!!"
    Exit Sub
End If

On Error Resume Next
    Set TimeSheet02 = Workbooks(Sheets("Command Sheet").Range("H2").Value)
On Error GoTo 0

If TimeSheet02 Is Nothing Then
    Set TimeSheet02 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Sheets("Command Sheet").Range("H2").Value, Password:=Sheets("Command Sheet").Range("I2"))

End If
```

' Open Timesheet Row 03

```
Dim TimeSheet03 As Workbook

If Dir(Sheets("Command Sheet").Range("H3").Value, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
    MsgBox "The Full path of " & Sheets("Command Sheet").Range("H3").Value & " does not exist!!"
    Exit Sub
End If

On Error Resume Next
    Set TimeSheet03 = Workbooks(Sheets("Command Sheet").Range("H3").Value)
On Error GoTo 0

If TimeSheet02 Is Nothing Then
    Set TimeSheet03 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Sheets("Command Sheet").Range("H3").Value, Password:=Sheets("Command Sheet").Range("I3"))

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved issue by resetting the focus back onto the master workbook after each file was opened...

Workbooks("master workbook").Activate